# Springer with Editor

Tags: publications, phd, springer

I just submitted my paper to a Springer journal. The status changed to *with editor* and then *decision process* . I thought the paper will be rejected as it didn't pass the prescreening phase but the status went down to *with editor* again and didn't change for 10 days now.

Should I contact the editor Or should I wait?

Comment: Wait. The first editor might felt unqualified to handle the paper so transferred it to another one. And it's winter break in many places, so be patient. I'd contact the editor after about a month of unchanged status.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Hope this is the case. I'm Ok with waiting but I was In doubt concerning the rejection based on the prescreening. Thank you

Comment: See also [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)

Comment: What field?  I am in math, and generally I do not contact the journal about a submitted paper until I have waited 6 months.

Comment: I'm in mathematics and Computer sciences. I work on computer vision algorithms. I see this is my first experience with Springer. My previous article was with Taylor and Francis. I did take about 6 months. But I was informed that my article in in review process after 1 month.

Answer (score 1):

"With editor" means an editor has been assigned, but no reviewers have been invited yet. "Decision in process" means the editor has made a recommendation to the editor-in-chief.

I'm guessing that the editor-in-chief disagreed with the editor, and either assigned a different editor or sent the manuscript back to the editor. I would say wait, although if it goes another ~1 week without the status changing I would write to the journal asking for an update. Two weeks should be sufficient for the editor to either make a decision, or to invite reviewers.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. based on your advice I'll wait for a third week and send a message to seek the current state of the article. Thank you again.

Comment: The editor in chief may also be on vacation, have a proposal deadline, or any other number of reasons why they haven't gotten to finalizing the decision yet. No email will change this -- have patience.

Comment: @Allure Please in springer journal is ''Reviewers Assigned'' means ''under review''? or just an invitation has been send to reviewers? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student I can't tell what the editorial management system says from the outside, but chances are, reviewers invited but haven't accepted the invitations yet.

Comment: @Allure Dear Allure, please I have  a submitted paper to some math springer journal it is under review since three months. Today the status is editor assigned. What this means? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like should answer all your questions.